# Older Post Issue on Search Label Pages

Tags: templates, themes, blogger

When i open the "/search/label/" pages, it shows "older" (sonraki) tab on the right corner of the page that goes nowhere .

Like: http://www.ahmetvarlik.com/search/label/Maketler%20ve%20Objeler

Here what happens when i click the this button: http://www.ahmetvarlik.com/search/label/Maketler%20ve%20Objeler?updated-max=2000-02-01T23:49:00-08:00&max-results=20&start=20&by-date=false

İ just want to delete this "older" (sonraki) section on my pages. (not from posts).

Can you help me?

Comment: Thank you Bassam. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code before `</body>` tag to hide blog pager on label pages

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isSearch'>
    <style>
        .blog-pager { display: none; }
    </style>
</b:if>
```